# Time constraint for datetime field

Tags: mysql

I Have a table and I would like to add a server-side time constraint in it for example start column: 2017/01/01 08:00 and the limit be 20:00 how can I achieve that? And if a value entered that doesn't fit the timeframe it is rejected.

Comment: `HINT`: `TRIGGER`

Comment: I dont think this can be configured in Mysql. What you are talking about is a combination of datetime and enum datatypes. I think you will have to put these checks at the application business logic and not at the database.